# Dynamic height of a column's child

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have this `Column`:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      flex: 2,
      child: Card(
        child: Text("Card")
      )
    ),
    Flexible(
      flex: 3,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Buttons
        ]
      )
    )
  ]
)
```

What I want to achieve is that the `Card` always has a flex of 2, and only gets smaller if the screen (or parent) is too small to render both the card and the buttons. However, with the code above, the card gets scaled down to its minimum size to contain the text, although there is space at the end of the screen.
Replacing the card's `Flexible` widget with an `Expanded` widget would fix this, but as I already said, it will never get smaller then, which will end up in a bottom overflow if the screen gets smaller (or the buttons get bigger).

Is there any way to achieve what I want? Or is this just a limitation of Flutter's rendering system?

Edit: I want to avoid making the screen scrollable.

Comment: On second column.. try `mainAxixSize: MainAxixSize.min`

Comment: @thenoobslayer Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably already know, `Flexible` *allows* its child to expand, but it does not *force* to do so. Viceversa, we use `Expanded` to force a child to occupy the remaining column/row.

Here's your options:

1. Use a `Flexible` Widget, and exploit its `fit` property: set it to `FlexFit.tight` to force it to fill the space (default is `FlexFit.loose`: the child can be *at most* as large as the available space, but is allowed to be smaller);
2. Use an `Expanded` Widget, since I sense that you want to occupy all the available space, *a priori*;
3. Mix these two approaches (`Flexible` on your `Card`, `Expanded` on your Buttons, or vice-versa)

In both cases, if some smaller screens are giving you trouble, consider making some elements scrollable: I don't know how big your `Card` is, but you could wrap it inside a `SingleChildScrollView`. Or, if you want try something else, you could make the whole screen scrollable with the same approach (you have to pay attention to that `Column`, though, as there is infinite height...)

Comment: Making the screen scrollable is exactly what I want to avoid.  The content of the card is quite small, so there should be no problem scaling it down in most cases.

Comment: Unless the buttons occupy most of the screen (in which case I'd make them scrollable), If I were you I'd make the `Column` containing the Card+the buttons (I assume both of these Widgets are very small) into a `SingleChildScrollView`, wrap them into a `Flexible` widget and exploiting the `fit` property, based on what you need. If these two mini-widgets are actually small I'm guessing that any screen can contain them... And the rest of the screen is fixed!